# Transformar Tabela HTML em Excel

Tags: php, html5, ajax, tabela-html

boa tarde!

Eu estou alguma tempo tentando transformar uma tabela dinamicamente vinda do banco para um arquivo Excel.

O procedimento que eu faço é pegar essa tabela via JavaScript, envia-la para um arquivo PHP via Ajax e nesse arquivo forçar o download da tabela em Excel. O que não está funcionando é "Forçar" o download do arquivo.

```js
// Gerar tabela statica via Ajax
    tabelaHtml = document.getElementById("table").innerHTML;

    $("#exportar").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "recebe-dados.php",
            cache: false,
            data:{
                origem: '<?php echo "$origem"; ?>',
                dadosExcel: tabelaHtml
            },
            success: function(e){
                alert("Dados exportados com sucesso!");
                console.log(e);
            },
            error: function(e){
                alert("Houve algum problema, tente novamente mais tarde!");
                console.error(e);
            } 
        });
    });
```

```html
<em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em>
    <tbody><tr class="separador">
         <td colspan="7">02/09/2019 &nbsp;&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong id="cont_1">2</strong></td>
       </tr><script>$("#cont_1").html("1");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>626</td>
        <td>Leandro Dutra Ribeiro</td>
        <td>leandro.durbeiro@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Icaraí</td>
        <td>(22) 98170-0530</td>
        <td>2019-09-02 10:10:20</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_1").html("2");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>627</td>
        <td>Pwmranbwajve</td>
        <td>poppyhaynes3565@gmail.com</td>        
        <td></td>
        <td>5066343676</td>
        <td>2019-09-02 21:45:42</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="separador">
         <td colspan="7">04/09/2019 &nbsp;&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong id="cont_2">3</strong></td>
       </tr><script>$("#cont_2").html("1");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>628</td>
        <td>Renata de Andrade Ribeiro</td>
        <td>renatadearibeiro@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Ilha</td>
        <td>(21) 97593-1215</td>
        <td>2019-09-04 07:13:23</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_2").html("2");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>629</td>
        <td>Juliana Candido Bastos Almeida</td>
        <td>julianacandidobetero@hotmail.com</td>        
        <td>Icaraí</td>
        <td>(21) 99748-4757</td>
        <td>2019-09-04 10:35:55</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_2").html("3");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>630</td>
        <td>Beatriz Imbroisi Ximenes</td>
        <td>biaimbroisi1@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Volta Redonda</td>
        <td>(21) 96450-4605</td>
        <td>2019-09-04 11:32:50</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="separador">
         <td colspan="7">05/09/2019 &nbsp;&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong id="cont_3">1</strong></td>
       </tr><script>$("#cont_3").html("1");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>631</td>
        <td>Beatriz Pensabem de Menezes Guimarães</td>
        <td>beatrizpensabem@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>São Gonçalo</td>
        <td>(21) 3583-3551</td>
        <td>2019-09-05 15:15:12</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="separador">
         <td colspan="7">06/09/2019 &nbsp;&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong id="cont_4">3</strong></td>
       </tr><script>$("#cont_4").html("1");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>632</td>
        <td>Maira de Souza</td>
        <td>mairaebranca@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Tijuca</td>
        <td>(21) 99488-3420</td>
        <td>2019-09-06 15:25:08</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_4").html("2");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>633</td>
        <td>Kelly Cristina Garcia de Figueiredo</td>
        <td>kellycgfig@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Tijuca</td>
        <td>(21) 98083-7461</td>
        <td>2019-09-06 17:26:28</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_4").html("3");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>634</td>
        <td>Daniele dos Santos Xavier</td>
        <td>anaclaraxavier777@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Icaraí</td>
        <td>(21) 99994-3168</td>
        <td>2019-09-06 19:18:51</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="separador">
         <td colspan="7">07/09/2019 &nbsp;&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong id="cont_5">2</strong></td>
       </tr><script>$("#cont_5").html("1");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>635</td>
        <td>Mariana Dias Sampaio</td>
        <td>marianasampaio.libras@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>São Gonçalo</td>
        <td>(21) 96511-5066</td>
        <td>2019-09-07 11:28:50</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_5").html("2");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>636</td>
        <td>Aclessiani</td>
        <td>aclessiani@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Volta Redonda</td>
        <td>(24) 99885-1763</td>
        <td>2019-09-07 14:41:06</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="separador">
         <td colspan="7">09/09/2019 &nbsp;&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong id="cont_6">7</strong></td>
       </tr><script>$("#cont_6").html("1");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>637</td>
        <td>Gazlcfudonkb</td>
        <td>danielwilliamson7992@gmail.com</td>        
        <td></td>
        <td>3069411081</td>
        <td>2019-09-09 08:40:17</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_6").html("2");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>638</td>
        <td>Vinícius  Alves Couzi</td>
        <td>viniciuscouzi@hotmail.com</td>        
        <td>Volta Redonda</td>
        <td>(24) 99878-2303</td>
        <td>2019-09-09 12:05:35</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_6").html("3");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>639</td>
        <td>Fernando Sergio Teixeira dos Santos</td>
        <td>fsergiobr@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Tijuca</td>
        <td>(21) 98135-8961</td>
        <td>2019-09-09 13:14:49</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_6").html("4");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>640</td>
        <td>Juliana Rodrigues  de Mello</td>
        <td>julianarmello7@hotmail.com</td>        
        <td>São Gonçalo</td>
        <td>(21) 97014-7127</td>
        <td>2019-09-09 14:44:59</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_6").html("5");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>641</td>
        <td>Juliana Rodrigues  de Mello</td>
        <td>julianarmello7@hotmail.com</td>        
        <td>São Gonçalo</td>
        <td>(21) 97014-7127</td>
        <td>2019-09-09 14:45:29</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_6").html("6");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>642</td>
        <td>Andrea Pinto Leite Ribeiro</td>
        <td>andreapintoleite@yahoo.com.br</td>        
        <td>Icaraí</td>
        <td>(21) 9832-58871</td>
        <td>2019-09-09 15:27:55</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_6").html("7");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>643</td>
        <td>Fernanda da Costa Diniz</td>
        <td>fernandadiniz915@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Icaraí</td>
        <td>(21) 99389-3390</td>
        <td>2019-09-09 16:27:17</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="separador">
         <td colspan="7">11/09/2019 &nbsp;&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong id="cont_7">5</strong></td>
       </tr><script>$("#cont_7").html("1");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>644</td>
        <td>Isabel C T Bergonzi</td>
        <td>isatrindadeb@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Tijuca</td>
        <td>(21) 98059-9201</td>
        <td>2019-09-11 07:09:13</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_7").html("2");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>645</td>
        <td>Thais Miguel</td>
        <td>thais.eng@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Volta Redonda</td>
        <td>24999553326</td>
        <td>2019-09-11 12:52:06</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_7").html("3");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>646</td>
        <td>Lislaine Sperandio Mendes</td>
        <td>lissperandio@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Icaraí</td>
        <td>(21) 98538-0528</td>
        <td>2019-09-11 14:42:12</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_7").html("4");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>647</td>
        <td>Paula Lopez</td>
        <td>paulafrlopez@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Tijuca</td>
        <td>(21) 97281-7709</td>
        <td>2019-09-11 17:21:14</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_7").html("5");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>648</td>
        <td>Talyne Mayana Ferreira Sales</td>
        <td>talynemayanaf@yahoo.com.br</td>        
        <td>Ilha</td>
        <td>(71) 99616-8935</td>
        <td>2019-09-11 20:22:06</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="separador">
         <td colspan="7">12/09/2019 &nbsp;&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong id="cont_8">3</strong></td>
       </tr><script>$("#cont_8").html("1");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>649</td>
        <td>Dora</td>
        <td>dorenilceviegas@hotmail.com</td>        
        <td>Ilha</td>
        <td>(21) 97415-8318</td>
        <td>2019-09-12 11:42:07</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_8").html("2");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>650</td>
        <td>Rosimeire Parra Macedo</td>
        <td>dra.rosimeire.adv@bol.com.br</td>        
        <td>Tijuca</td>
        <td>(21) 98170-5838</td>
        <td>2019-09-12 21:51:00</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_8").html("3");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>651</td>
        <td>Rosimeire Parra Macedo</td>
        <td>dra.rosimeire.adv@bol.com.br</td>        
        <td>Tijuca</td>
        <td>(21) 98170-5838</td>
        <td>2019-09-12 21:51:37</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="separador">
         <td colspan="7">13/09/2019 &nbsp;&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong id="cont_9">7</strong></td>
       </tr><script>$("#cont_9").html("1");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>652</td>
        <td>Teste Pai</td>
        <td>teste@teste.com.br</td>        
        <td>Volta Redonda</td>
        <td>(24) 99999-9999</td>
        <td>2019-09-13 10:52:16</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_9").html("2");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>653</td>
        <td>Aluno Teste Setembro</td>
        <td>aluno@aluno.com.br</td>        
        <td>Volta Redonda</td>
        <td>(24) 12345-6789</td>
        <td>2019-09-13 11:51:36</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_9").html("3");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>654</td>
        <td>Davi Teodoro Pereira</td>
        <td>daviteo@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Volta Redonda</td>
        <td>(24) 99831-3816</td>
        <td>2019-09-13 11:53:12</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_9").html("4");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>655</td>
        <td>Luciana Barcellos de Paula Motta</td>
        <td>lubarpa45@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Volta Redonda</td>
        <td>(24) 99257-9444</td>
        <td>2019-09-13 15:29:24</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_9").html("5");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>656</td>
        <td>Narciso Felicio de Lima Junior</td>
        <td>narcisojr.rj@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Ilha</td>
        <td>(21) 98082-0991</td>
        <td>2019-09-13 17:45:48</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_9").html("6");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>657</td>
        <td>Leonardo Mendes Santiago</td>
        <td>lmsantiago@hotmail.com</td>        
        <td>Tijuca</td>
        <td>(21) 98292-5932</td>
        <td>2019-09-13 20:58:53</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_9").html("7");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>658</td>
        <td>Juan Filgueiras</td>
        <td>j.phelipe@bol.com.br</td>        
        <td>Tijuca</td>
        <td>21967796737</td>
        <td>2019-09-13 23:37:10</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="separador">
         <td colspan="7">14/09/2019 &nbsp;&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong id="cont_10">2</strong></td>
       </tr><script>$("#cont_10").html("1");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>659</td>
        <td>Patrícia de Abreu Cândido</td>
        <td>patriciapclaudio@yahoo.com.br</td>        
        <td>Volta Redonda</td>
        <td>(24) 97401-5585</td>
        <td>2019-09-14 17:02:54</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_10").html("2");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>660</td>
        <td>Lucia de Figueiredo Souza Rodrigues</td>
        <td>lucia.naturalmenteorganicos@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Tijuca</td>
        <td>(21) 97681-6929</td>
        <td>2019-09-14 21:41:49</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="separador">
         <td colspan="7">15/09/2019 &nbsp;&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong id="cont_11">2</strong></td>
       </tr><script>$("#cont_11").html("1");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>661</td>
        <td>Karine Conceição da Costa</td>
        <td>karineconceicaodacosta@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Tijuca</td>
        <td>(21) 97022-0975</td>
        <td>2019-09-15 21:32:18</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_11").html("2");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>662</td>
        <td>Karine Conceição da Costa</td>
        <td>karineconceicaodacosta@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Tijuca</td>
        <td>(21) 97022-0975</td>
        <td>2019-09-15 21:34:03</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="separador">
         <td colspan="7">16/09/2019 &nbsp;&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong id="cont_12">7</strong></td>
       </tr><script>$("#cont_12").html("1");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>663</td>
        <td>Ferbando António Orlando da Rocha</td>
        <td>rocha.fer@uol.com.br</td>        
        <td>Volta Redonda</td>
        <td>(24) 99215-8008</td>
        <td>2019-09-16 11:56:38</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_12").html("2");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>664</td>
        <td>Ferbando António Orlando da Rocha</td>
        <td>rocha.fer@uol.com.br</td>        
        <td>Volta Redonda</td>
        <td>(24) 99215-8008</td>
        <td>2019-09-16 11:57:41</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_12").html("3");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>665</td>
        <td>Mariana Leao</td>
        <td>maryleao@yahoo.com</td>        
        <td>Tijuca</td>
        <td>(21) 98272-7716</td>
        <td>2019-09-16 13:42:48</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_12").html("4");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>666</td>
        <td>Priscilla Cruz</td>
        <td>priscillacruz18@hotmail.com</td>        
        <td>Tijuca</td>
        <td>(21) 96913-3837</td>
        <td>2019-09-16 14:37:31</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_12").html("5");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>667</td>
        <td>Flavio da Cruz Lima</td>
        <td>flaviocruz0403@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Icaraí</td>
        <td>(71) 99984-4516</td>
        <td>2019-09-16 14:43:51</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_12").html("6");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>668</td>
        <td>Flavio da Cruz Lima</td>
        <td>flaviocruz0403@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Icaraí</td>
        <td>(71) 99984-4516</td>
        <td>2019-09-16 14:44:29</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_12").html("7");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>669</td>
        <td>Adelcio Lara de Resende</td>
        <td>adelciolara@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Icaraí</td>
        <td>(31) 98801-0454</td>
        <td>2019-09-16 16:13:05</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="separador">
         <td colspan="7">17/09/2019 &nbsp;&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong id="cont_13">11</strong></td>
       </tr><script>$("#cont_13").html("1");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>670</td>
        <td>Juliana Silva</td>
        <td>juliana_jubi@yahoo.com.br</td>        
        <td>Tijuca</td>
        <td>(21) 99389-2663</td>
        <td>2019-09-17 09:25:23</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_13").html("2");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>671</td>
        <td>Ana Paula Araujo A. Vieira</td>
        <td>anapvieira@hotmail.com</td>        
        <td>Icaraí</td>
        <td>(21) 9791-25083</td>
        <td>2019-09-17 12:39:01</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_13").html("3");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>672</td>
        <td>Sheila da Silva Amaral</td>
        <td>sheilas1@uol.com.br</td>        
        <td>Icaraí</td>
        <td>(21) 98331-5005</td>
        <td>2019-09-17 13:16:46</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_13").html("4");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>673</td>
        <td>Fernando Oliveira Pinto</td>
        <td>fernanop@bol.com.br</td>        
        <td>Volta Redonda</td>
        <td>(24) 9817-41423</td>
        <td>2019-09-17 15:31:34</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_13").html("5");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>674</td>
        <td>Rondinele Santos Andrade</td>
        <td>rondmg@yahoo.com.br</td>        
        <td>São Gonçalo</td>
        <td>(21) 99691-0618</td>
        <td>2019-09-17 15:31:49</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_13").html("6");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>675</td>
        <td>Lorena Ribeiro Molinaro</td>
        <td>loreneventoskids01@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Icaraí</td>
        <td>(21) 99115-0506</td>
        <td>2019-09-17 15:34:38</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_13").html("7");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>676</td>
        <td>Luzivanda Almeida de Oliveira</td>
        <td>luzioliveiray@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Ilha</td>
        <td>(21) 98881-6044</td>
        <td>2019-09-17 15:38:34</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_13").html("8");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>677</td>
        <td>William Alves Ferreira</td>
        <td>williamjunior1210@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Tijuca</td>
        <td>(24) 99843-0984</td>
        <td>2019-09-17 17:08:34</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_13").html("9");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>678</td>
        <td>Elismar Batista Duarte</td>
        <td>elis.tuquinha@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Ilha</td>
        <td>(21) 99568-0934</td>
        <td>2019-09-17 19:05:56</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_13").html("10");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>679</td>
        <td>Marcelo de Souza Mendonça</td>
        <td>mds.mendonca.vr@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Volta Redonda</td>
        <td>(24) 3350-0532</td>
        <td>2019-09-17 21:50:21</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_13").html("11");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>680</td>
        <td>Marcelo Braga</td>
        <td>braga.marcelobraga@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Ilha</td>
        <td>(21) 98686-1207</td>
        <td>2019-09-17 22:04:08</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="separador">
         <td colspan="7">18/09/2019 &nbsp;&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong id="cont_14">4</strong></td>
       </tr><script>$("#cont_14").html("1");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>681</td>
        <td>Diane Cunha Gonçalves</td>
        <td>dianegoncalves@yahoo.com</td>        
        <td>Volta Redonda</td>
        <td>(24) 99237-7926</td>
        <td>2019-09-18 12:08:46</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_14").html("2");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>682</td>
        <td>Lucilene</td>
        <td>lucilene.gayani@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Tijuca</td>
        <td>(21) 98371-4577</td>
        <td>2019-09-18 14:07:57</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_14").html("3");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>683</td>
        <td>Nathalia Lameira Lisboa</td>
        <td>natlisboaa@yahoo.com.br</td>        
        <td>Icaraí</td>
        <td>(21) 98077-1729</td>
        <td>2019-09-18 17:41:00</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_14").html("4");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>684</td>
        <td>Sergio Guimarães Soares</td>
        <td>soaresttai@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>São Gonçalo</td>
        <td>(21) 97349-0967</td>
        <td>2019-09-18 21:36:16</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="separador">
         <td colspan="7">19/09/2019 &nbsp;&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong id="cont_15">4</strong></td>
       </tr><script>$("#cont_15").html("1");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>685</td>
        <td>Neuza Maria Gomes Leao</td>
        <td>nmgleao@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Tijuca</td>
        <td>(21) 99266-0311</td>
        <td>2019-09-19 10:30:48</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_15").html("2");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>686</td>
        <td>Deyse Sant Anna dos Santos</td>
        <td>deyse.uerj@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>São Gonçalo</td>
        <td>(21) 98825-6713</td>
        <td>2019-09-19 15:30:41</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_15").html("3");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>687</td>
        <td>Staffony Katry Fonseca dos Santos</td>
        <td>staffony@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>São Gonçalo</td>
        <td>(21) 99096-3737</td>
        <td>2019-09-19 19:11:35</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_15").html("4");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>688</td>
        <td>Marcia Loredo Pereira</td>
        <td>aicrammlp@hotmail.com</td>        
        <td>Ilha</td>
        <td>(21) 98341-8920</td>
        <td>2019-09-19 22:56:15</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="separador">
         <td colspan="7">20/09/2019 &nbsp;&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong id="cont_16">3</strong></td>
       </tr><script>$("#cont_16").html("1");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>689</td>
        <td>Juliana</td>
        <td>jullyvicente@hotmail.com</td>        
        <td>São Gonçalo</td>
        <td>(21) 98400-9468</td>
        <td>2019-09-20 16:18:48</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    <script>$("#cont_16").html("2");</script>    <tr name="tr_table">
        <td>690</td>
        <td>Mariana Pinto Vieira Souto</td>
        <td>marianadt7@gmail.com</td>        
        <td>Volta Redonda</td>
        <td>(22) 99787-4749</td>
        <td>2019-09-20 19:54:40</td>
        <td><em>mv1.com.br | LP Pré-matrícula</em></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

CÓDIGO PHP ABAIXO:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['dadosExcel']) && $_POST['dadosExcel'] != ''){

    $nomeTabela = $_POST['origem'];

    $tabela = $_POST['dadosExcel'];

    $arquivo = $nomeTabela . '.xls';

    header('Content-Type: application/x-msexcel');
    header('Content-type: application/force-download');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$arquivo}\"");
    header("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data" );

    /*header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$arquivo.xls");        
    header("Pragma: no-cache");*/

    echo $arquivo;
    echo $tabela;


}else{
    echo "Não possivel completar a exportação!";
}
```

*** Algumas soluções que eu tentei foi chamar o arquivo no topo do documento antes de qualquer html, o que não funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Salve o código abaixo com a extensão XLS:

    
    
    
        
            
                1
                2
            
            
                3
                4

Para a exportação, use o Data URI, que permite adicionar dados nem um endereço. 
Monte este código e coloque na tabela um id:

    
    
        Página Exemplo
    
    
        th > td {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin quis blandit ante. Ut nec urna luctus, sodales purus sagittis, convallis orci. Cras non tincidunt augue.

Duis tempor est non tortor placerat, sed malesuada tellus rhoncus. Suspendisse quis ligula ut magna finibus luctus. Integer sollicitudin lectus non erat imperdiet, id suscipit eros ultricies. Morbi vel congue neque. Curabitur varius nibh nec purus cursus ullamcorper.

Janeiro
                    Fevereiro
                    Março
                    Abril
                    Maio
                    Junho
                
            
            
                
                    Valor
                    123.45
                    567.89
                    901.23
                    456.78
                    234.56
                    789.01
                
                
                    Valor
                    901.45
                    456.62
                    234.94
                    478.91
                    870.11
                    123.67
                
            
        
        Salva Planilha
    
    
        function salvaPlanilha() {

```
    }
</script>
```

crie um Data URI com base na tabela, isole o código da tabela:

function salvaPlanilha() {
    var htmlPlanilha = "" + document.getElementById("tabela").innerHTML + "";
}

coloque as informações num endereço
function salvaPlanilha() {
    var htmlPlanilha = "" + document.getElementById("tabela").innerHTML + "";

```
var htmlBase64 = btoa(htmlPlanilha);
```

}

una as duas primeiras informações

function salvaPlanilha() {
    var htmlPlanilha = "" + document.getElementById("tabela").innerHTML + "";

```
var htmlBase64 = btoa(htmlPlanilha);
var link = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64," + htmlBase64;
```

}

para o navegador baixar o arquivo basta forçar o acesso ao endereço

function salvaPlanilha() {
    var htmlPlanilha = "" + document.getElementById("tabela").innerHTML + "";

```
var htmlBase64 = btoa(htmlPlanilha);
var link = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64," + htmlBase64;

window.open(link);
```

}